# There is any equivalent for TOP and BOTTOM in SQL that available in influxdb?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I am porting the queries in influx DB to timescaleDB (Postgres SQL). I am currently stuck in the [TOP](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#top) and [BOTTOM](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#bottom) functions. Is there any equivalent in Postgres SQL or any suggestions to achieve it?

For constant one, I did like that,

```
TOP('field', 1)    -> MAX('field')
BOTTOM('field', 1) -> MIN('field')
```

What about others like,

```
TOP('field', 5)
BOTTOM('field', 5)
```

Edit 1:

Does Using LIMIT with ORDER BY also work with GROUP BY because the limit is executed after group by Right What if want something like [this](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#select-the-bottom-three-field-values-associated-with-a-field-key-and-include-several-clauses)

Thank You

Comment: Use `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`

Comment: But What about Group By, the limit is executed after Group by right ? What if I want something like [this](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#select-the-bottom-three-field-values-associated-with-a-field-key-and-include-several-clauses)

Comment: Then you can use a subquery with the  `ROW_NUMBER` function on the `GROUP BY` results  and `WHERE` clause to get rows with row number <= N to get top N rows for each group

Comment: Would you like to open an issue to support this in Timescale Toolkit? I love the ask and I think we can definitely work on something here! https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using window functions is probably the most versatile way to do this:

```
select *
from (
   select t.*, 
          dense_rank() over (partition by ??? order by ??? asc) as rnk
   from the_table t
) x
where x.rnk = 3; --<< adjust here
```

Rows in a relational database have no implied sort order. So "top" or "bottom" only makes sense if you also provide an `order by`. From your question is completely unclear what that would be.

Using `order by .. asc` returns the "bottom rows", using `order by .. desc` returns the "top rows"

If you want top/bottom for the entire table (instead of one row "per group"), the leave out the `partition by`

`dense_rank()` will return multiple rows with the same "rank" when the rows have the same highest (or lowest) value in the column you are sorting by. If you don't want that (and pick an arbitrary one from those "duplicates") then use `row_number()` instead.